# Как исправить проблему с масштабированием?

Tags: windows, winforms, масштабирование

В приложениях (предположительно с использованием windows forms) наблюдается нечёткий шрифт и элементы в целом, они как будто "размыты":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках стоит масштабирование 125%. Это рекомендуемое значение и всё работает исправно, кроме некоторых приложений.

При изменении масштабирования на 100% проблема уходит, но всё остальное становится настолько маленьким, что пользоваться компьютером не очень комфортно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пути решения этой проблемы

Дополнительная информация: Windows 11, видеодрайвер последний, directX12, .netframework 4.8

Comment: Используйте .NET 6+. [Здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/6.0/application-bootstrap) приведён пример bootstraper'a.

Comment: @XelaNimed, у меня проблема со сторонними приложениями, а не с моим, не думаю, что это поможет

Comment: [Тыц](https://qna.habr.com/q/522145), [тыц](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), [тыц](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/extensibility/addressing-dpi-issues2?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).

Comment: @XelaNimed, видел, это не помогло, неужели придётся dpi для каждого приложения выставлять?

Comment: И даже это может не помочь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить с помощью **ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОЙ** настройки масштабирования с тем же значением 125%, всё осталось прежним, но размытость пропала.

Найти можно в **Система > Дисплей > Масштаб**.
Нужно вписать ваше значение.

Проблема, которая появляется в результате этих действий: Некрасивое расположение значков на рабочем столе (изменилось расстояние между ними). Исправил с помощью утилиты **Desktop Icon Spacing**

Answer (score 1):

должен помочь переход на другой .net и если это не помогает, то размытие - это функция специальная. если не помогло - я нашел с исправление этой проблемы:

> Нажмите кнопку "  Пуск ", а затем выберите параметры >  уведомлений системы > & действия, а затем отключите Параметры отображения.

> Выполните одно из следующих действий в зависимости от того, отобразился ли запрос "Исправить размытость в приложениях?"
> Если запрос отобразился, выберите Да, открыть параметры и нажмите кнопку Применить.
> Если запрос не отображается, в поле поиска на панели задач введите дополнительные параметры масштабирования и выберите Исправить размытость в приложениях.
> В окне Устранение масштабирования для приложений включите Windows, чтобы попытаться исправить приложения, чтобы они не были размыты.

> Независимо от того, были ли у вас размытые приложения или вы видели уведомление о неразмытых приложениях, вы можете включить или выключить эту функцию в любое время.
> В поле поиска на панели задач введите Дополнительные параметры масштабирования и выберите пункт исправить неразмытые приложения.
> Если вы хотите устранить масштабирование для приложений, включите или отключите, чтобы Windows попытается исправить приложения, чтобы они не были размыты.

нашел на сайте https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-windows-10-e9fe34ab-e7e7-bc6f-6695-cb169b51de0f

пожалуйста, пометь это сообщение правильным или лучшим, мне это очень поможет:)

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло. У меня нет пункта "размытие приложений"

Comment: тогда уже обратись в саму службу поддержки по винде. удачи вам, надеюсь ответят